# How can I fix GoLang's LDAP Filter Operations Error?

Tags: go, ldap, ldap-query

So I am new to GoLang and I am trying to make a LDAP filter. However, I keep getting the following error:

```
LDAP Result Code 1 "Operations Error": 000020D6: SvcErr: DSID-031007E5, problem 5012 (DIR_ERROR), data 0
```

I read in here ([LDAP Errors](https://ldap.com/ldap-result-code-reference-core-ldapv3-result-codes/#rc-operationsError)) that "Operations Error" happens when either not all the necessary calls have been made or the order of operation of the calls is wrong.

I am honestly not sure, what I might be missing and or what I am doing wrong.

My code is the following

```
 import (
    "crypto/tls"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/go-ldap/ldap/v3"
    "log"
)


func ApiCaller(){
    // The username and password we want to check
    username := "username"
    password := "password"

    //Establishing connection to the LDAP server
    l, err := ldap.Dial("tcp", "exampleURL.com:389")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // Closing connection in case of error
    defer l.Close()

    // Reconnect with TLS
    err = l.StartTLS(&tls.Config{InsecureSkipVerify: true})
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // Bind as the user to verify their password
    err = l.Bind(username, password)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    // Setting up the search criterias with filter
    searchRequest := ldap.NewSearchRequest(
        "OU=OUg_Applications",
        ldap.ScopeWholeSubtree, ldap.NeverDerefAliases, 0, 0, false,
        fmt.Sprintf("(&(OU=OUg_Applications))"),
        []string{""},
        nil,
    )

    // Performing search in the LDAP Server
    sr, err := l.Search(searchRequest)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(sr.Entries)
}
```

Comment: Your start DN doesn't look correct. First parameter of the search call. It should be the DN of a location in the DIT. You don't need the `&` in the filter, as you only have one term, and removing it will then result in redundant parentheses.

Comment: Verify your query is correct using command-line tools e.g. `ldapsearch -D username -w password -b OU=OUg_Applications '(&(OU=OUg_Applications))'` - before trying compiled code. As @user207421 mentioned, the base-DN looks off - it should end in `o=example.com` etc.  Also possibly comment out the StartTLS section until you get a basic connection working.

Comment: Thanks @colminator and user207421. My base-DN was off. It was "DC=example,DC=com", instead. You guys are life savors!

Comment: @user207421 what is DIT?

Comment: DIT = "Directory Information Tree"

Comment: You should have asked @user207421 to make his comment into an answer and receive the proper credit for this - that's what I would have done.  Think community here.  Instead you took his comment (which gave the answer) and made it into a self-answer then self-marked it.  I mean, I'm glad you confirmed the solution.  Don't get me wrong.  But it's unfortunate that user207421 will never get the proper credit for this, IMHO.

Comment: @user207421 I am sorry that I did not do what T-Heron highlighted. I meant no harm by it. I just did not think about it. If you want, go on and put an answer and I will mark it. Sorry again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question comments helped me figure it out. My base-DN was off. It was  supposed to be "DC=example,DC=com", instead of "OU=OUg_Applications".